# FDT: An internal error occurred during debugging

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, fdt

I'm using FDT 3 enterprise with Flex 4.5 SDK on Mac OSX

Running works fine.

Debugging throws an internal error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.debug.concrete.FDBVersionTools.versionParts(FDBVersionTools.java:44)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.debug.concrete.FDBVersionTools.compare(FDBVersionTools.java:19)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.debug.concrete.FDBVersionTools.lessOrEqual(FDBVersionTools.java:7)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.debug.concrete.FDBVersionTools.inRange(FDBVersionTools.java:54)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.core.debugger.adapter.FlexSdkVersionTools.covers(FlexSdkVersionTools.java:25)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.core.debugger.adapter.FDBAdapterLoader.cover(FDBAdapterLoader.java:51)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.core.debugger.adapter.FlexDebuggerLoader.searchAdapterLoader(FlexDebuggerLoader.java:88)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.core.debugger.adapter.FlexDebuggerLoader.loadDebugger(FlexDebuggerLoader.java:81)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.DebugSessionManager.getDebuggerFor(DebugSessionManager.java:50)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.DebugSessionManager.launchSessionFor(DebugSessionManager.java:106)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.core.launch.DebugSessionManager.launchSessionAndKillOld(DebugSessionManager.java:146)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.ui.launch.StartDebuggerTestLaunchConfigurationDelegate.startDebugger(StartDebuggerTestLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:36)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.ui.launch.fcsh.MxmlcLaunchConfigurationDelegate.startDebugger(MxmlcLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:348)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.ui.launch.fcsh.AbstractFCSHLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(AbstractFCSHLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:174)
at com.powerflasher.fdt.internal.ui.launch.fcsh.MxmlcLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(MxmlcLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:237)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:866)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1069)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I'm not using any uncommon debug/compiler-arguments

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: You're in the wrong place for this. Try PowerFlasher's bug database: http://bugs.powerflasher.com/jira/, or upgrade FDT (it's at 5.5 as of yesterday, and the licensing model has greatly improved - no reason to stick with an IDE that's outdated, especially when you're working with current SDKs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flex Debugger API changed quite a bit from Flex 3.X - 4.0. This means that your older FDT (version 3.x) is likely not compatible with later Flex SDKs. That is why you are getting that error.

You'll need to upgrade to 5.5 (or FDT 4.5 if you have a FDT 4 license)b/c the FDT team has had to rewrite parts of the debugger to make it compatible with Flex 4.5+.  We've done our best to keep the upgrade price minimal.

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/buy-download/

Comment: Ah ok, well, we only have a 3.x license. So that means I will not be able to use debugging with new SDK's.

Comment: The strange thing is that I cán debug with SDK 4.6 (i get a lot of warnings though which force me to build 3 times) but not with SDK 4.5.

On the other hand I don't find €299,- minimal since we already paid €599,- for v3.

Comment: I agree that 299 is a lot for a single version upgrade, but going from FDT 3 - 5.5 is two versions. FDT 3 also came about about 5 years ago.

Comment: Right, that's a long time ago. We renewed our license ;)